# jQuery ajax wrong data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one error in my code.

Error is a my link is not same

```
$(".demo-ajax").hovercard({
     detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
     width: 350,
     onHoverIn: function () {
         // set your twitter id
         var projeID = $('a.demo-ajax').attr("href").match(/projeID=([0-9]+)/)[1];
         var linkler = "bilgiler.php?id=" + projeID;
         $.ajax({
             url: linkler,
             context: document.body,
             success: function(data){
                 alert(linkler);
                 $('.twitter-username').html(data);
             }
         });
     }
});
```

and then,

```
<a href="proje.php?projeID=2" class="demo-ajax">zzzzzz</a>
<a href="proje.php?projeID=1" class="demo-ajax">ssss</a>
```

if i go to "ssss" , i have alert : "proje.php?projeID=2"

Why i have this error.

Have a good day.

new code blocks :

```
    var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<hr><p><p></p><label class="twitter-username">the user</label></p><ul id="demo-cb-tweets"></ul>';

        $(".demo-ajax").hovercard({
            detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
            width: 350,

            onHoverIn: function () {
                // set your twitter id

                var projeID = $(this).attr('href').match(/projeID=([0-9]+)/)[1];
                var linkler = "bilgiler.php?id=" + projeID;
                alert(linkler);
            $.ajax({
              url: linkler,
              context: document.body,
              success: function(data){

                    $('.twitter-username').html(data);
              }
            });

            }
        });
```

if i use this,

i don't have any alert and i go to difference link and i see the user ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to the **current** element:

```
var projeID = $(this).attr("href").match(/projeID=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

By having `$('a.demo-ajax').attr("href")` you always read the *href* attribute of the **first** element in the collection, if such exists.

**Edit**: Looks like the `hovercard` method is being applied to some containing `<div>` element rather then to the anchor itself, so change the code to:

```
var oLink = $(this).find("a");
var projeID = oLink.attr("href").match(/projeID=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

Comment: @Shiplu 39 seconds according to the timestamps.. :-)

Comment: [offtopic] Where to see the timestamp?

Comment: @Shiplu hover the mouse over the "x mins ago" to see the full exact time. :)

Comment: @CWOmer what do you mean? What you see now in the alert? Do you get error?

Comment: @ShadowWizard i don't see this is not working. there aren't any alert

Comment: @CWOmer put the alert right after the `var linkler = "bilgiler.php?id=" + projeID;` line. Also, check for scripting errors using JavaScript console.

Comment: @CWOmer weird, it should work. Add this line: `alert(this + "\n" + $(this));` right after the `// set your twitter id` line. What do you see now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard [object HTMLDivElement]
[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

`alert(linkler);` cause the alert in your code. Remove it should silent it.

I also doubt that the alert should be `bilgiler.php?id=2`

This problem with linkler not changing is caused by your selector $('a.demo-ajax'), you should fix it by applying $(this).attr('href') ...

`$('a.demo-ajax').attr('href')` always load your first link element.

`$(this)` will select the link you have hovered on.

Comment: i will delete but if i deleted, linkler is to the same again

i want linkler is not same because second link href is proje.php?projeID=1.However this is proje.php?projeID=2

Comment: This problem is caused by your selector `$('a.demo-ajax')`, you should fix it by applying `$(this).attr('href')` ...